# Delete command not working

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want to ask that what is wrong with that code. I am running this and nothing is changed to the data source.

```
DataRow[] dr = this.U_dt.Select("UserName='"+user+"'");
DataRow dr1 = dr[0];

//U_ad is a dataadapter
//U_dt is a datatable. U_ad.fill(U_dt);

this.U_dt.Rows.Remove(dr1);
U_ad.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("Delete from [Users] where [UserName]=@User", con);
U_ad.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "[UserName]");

this.U_ad.Update(U_dt);
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok thanks Sir I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass, as value for the parameter `@User` a string `"[UserName]"`.
This is not the value of a variable containing the user name to search for deletion, but a literal string.
Of course nothing is found in the column `UserName` with a literal value `"[UserName]"`

Try instead to use the variable `user` that you have applied in the Select before

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from [Users] where [UserName]=@User", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, user);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have used directly the SqlCommand `ExecuteNonQuery` method, but this should work also using the `DeleteCommand` of a `SqlDataAdapter`

Comment: Try to replace the line that creates the parameter with: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", user);`

Comment: Try to get the return value from ExecuteNonQuery(). It should be 1 if it has found the user to delete, it is 0 if the user is not found. While at it verify also the value of the variable user and check if a user with the supplied name exists

Comment: Also, column of type nchar will pad their value with spaces to fill the column lenght. So if your user is 'JOHN' in the column there are 16 more spaces to fill out the fixed length column. If it is possible, try to change your column to nvarchar datatype.

Comment: Any news on this problem? Seems that the other (copycat) answer worked, so I am just wondering what was the error on mine?

Answer (score 0):

can you put  your code in try catch like

```
try{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from [Users] where [UserName]=@User", con);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, user);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}catch(Exception ex)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine( "  ERROR:" + ex.Message );
}
```

Also there maybe some foreign key which might cause you not to delete the entry. Its always wise to put these sql queries in try catch for safety.
This might help [ADO.net simple project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155/Simple-ADO-NET-Database-Read-Insert-Update-and-Del)

Comment: I did the comand.executenonquery method on this and it was successful.. the code dont return any errors and dont go to the catch block

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you remove the row you want to delete from your datatable before calling update ... the update command iterates the rows in your datatable and executes your delete command for all rows with rowstate == Deleted ... but your row has been removed from your datatable so the delete command wont get executed at all.

possible solutions would be to just execute U_ad.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() (after settings the @User parameter) and not call DataAdapter.Update at all or to execute dr1.Delete() instead of this.U_dt.Rows.Remove(dr1) and call DataAdapter.Update